# Why is an additional backslash '\' being added to substring in list when re.split is used?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split

So I'm trying to solve an issue in my code where an additional backslash is added to a substring(s) in my split list once re.split(regex_pattern, str) is used.  The problem goes something like this:

```
In [63]: str = r'/dir/hello\/hell/dir2/hello\end'

In [64]: regex_pattern = '(hello)'

In [65]: a = re.split(regex_pattern, str)

In [66]: a
Out[66]: ['/dir/', 'hello', '\\/hell/dir2/', 'hello', '\\end']
```

As you can see, Out[66] shows the list as having two substrings with '\\' instead of two with '\'.  I know this problem has something to do with how the compiler interprets backslashes, but ultimately cannot figure out why specifically this is happening.

I've also tried making my str variable a raw string, and adding additional '\' to my str variable (up to four '\\\\') where one exists, i.e.

```
In [63]: str = r'/dir/hello\\/hell/dir2/hello\\end'
```

This still gives the same output.

I am using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu.  Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a question whose answer applies to mine.

Comment: Basically, don't worry about it. It's only changing the way your list is being represented when you print it to the screen, but the actual string doesn't have any extra slashes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to with `re.split`. `\` usually defines an escape sequence. To use a literal `\` you'll need to double it:

Consider your original string:

```
In [15]: s = r'/dir/hello\/hell/dir2/hello\end'

In [16]: s
Out[16]: '/dir/hello\\/hell/dir2/hello\\end'

In [17]: len(s)
Out[17]: 31
```

The extra `\` are not counted with `len`. They only help to specify that the `\` does not define any other escape sequence; asides `\\` which is also an escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you. Nice pointing out how it doesn't affect len() as well!